# Expo React Native User Data for screens

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-context

I'm currently using this function after the user has signed in to pull data from their doc that was created on account registration:

```
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
    const user = auth.currentUser;

    const getUser = async() => {
        const currentUser = await firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get()
        .then((documentSnapshot) => {
          if( documentSnapshot.exists ) {
            setUserData(documentSnapshot.data());
          }
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getUser();
    }, [])
```

With this I can then call specific data like `{userData.displayName}` only issue is when updates are made it doesn't pull through so its not realtime. From reading It seems my function needs to be a `onSnapshot` instead of the `documentSnapshot` I've been using if I'm correct?

My question is - I assume it's better to use context somewhere to only pull in once with a listener to update real time and then just pull that through to any screen correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a `Context`. If you just want to add a realtime listener you can overrie you code to something like this:

```js
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
const user = auth.currentUser;

useEffect(() => {
  const doc = db.collection("users").doc(user.uid);

  const observer = doc.onSnapshot(
    (docSnapshot) => {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        setUserData(documentSnapshot.data());
      }
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
    }
  );

  return observer();
}, []);
```